# MVC 5 application routing not working after adding DevExpress controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-10, devexpress, devextreme, iis-10

I am working on a pure MVC 5 application. I added a feature that required me to use DevExpress gridview for its powerful functionality.

After having worked with the DevExpress control and had it working, the page had a problem with the existing jQuery menu scripts so I changed the menu to use the DevExpress navigation control. This required me to update my scripts which I did.

So the application is fully functioning on my DEV environment but when I deployed it on a Windows 10 with IIS 10 server, the routing is failing for all pages, except the landing page. I can't navigate to any of the pages on the site.

When adding DevExpress, changes were automatically made to my Web.config and I also made a change to the RouteConfig.cs file.

**I added this to RouteConfig.cs:**
`routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}")`

I have searched and tried different things but haven't found a solution. Please help as this is holding me up.

**NB:** I am writing this post using a phone so I am unable to post the Web.config but will do so when I can.

Comment: Why don't you contact the DevExpress Support directly?

Comment: Mikhail I have checked the DevExpress threads relating to this question and they pointed the issue on server (IIS) or application config. They say the issue is beyond their scope because it's not a direct DevExpress issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching through the Web.config I found the issue, under `<appsettings>` the **'ApplicationEnvironment'** key was set to **Local** instead of **Server**. After changing that, all is well and good.

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.